# 'se-packagr' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, smartedit, rush

After 'rush build' I received
'se-packagr' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
Any idea how to fix it? Screen attached below. Thank you.

[image: problem in cmd]